# Data is not getting listed using <ul><li> tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jsp

I am trying following code to list the data using `<ul><li>` tags in javascript .But  bullets are displaying  only in first data not all data.

```
  var prjlist;
    var output; 
    var proh;
    var statuss;
    var status;


    for (var i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < responseText.length; j++) {          


      prjlist= responseText[j].projectDescription;
      statuss= '<ul><li>'+ responseText[j].currentStatus + '</li></ul>';

     /*  output= prjlist.split("&");
      proh=output.join("/n");
       */
     proh=prjlist.replace(/&/g, '<br>');
     status =statuss.replace(/&/g, '<br>');

            var Obj = {

                projectName: '<h3>'+ responseText[j].projectName +'</h3>',

                projectDescription: '<p>'+ proh + '<p>',


                 currentStatus: '<b>'+ "Current Status:" +'</b>' + '<br>'+  status 
                }
```

I am getting following output from DB for current Status value.

[image]

Comment: Something is not right on this line: `statuss= '<ul><li>'+ responseText[j].currentStatus + '</li></ul>';`

Comment: create a working jsfiddle example of your code.. cuz it is unclear that what actually causing the problem.

Comment: @ManojShukla, As i have shown  output image .. Bullets in curent status is coming only first record.I want to display on all the records

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering `<ul>` in every iteration in your `for` loops.

You should render the `<ul>` once(before the loop starts), then render the `<li>` inside the loop, then close the `</ul>` tag after the loop.

e.g.

```
var statuss = '<ul>';

for () {
   statuss += '<li>'+ responseText[j].currentStatus + '</li>';
}

statuss += '</ul>';
```

Full code here:

```
var prjlist;
var output;
var proh;
var statuss = '<ul>';
var status;

for (var i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < responseText.length; j++) {
    prjlist = responseText[j].projectDescription;
    statuss += '<li>' + responseText[j].currentStatus + '</li>';

    /*  output= prjlist.split("&");
     proh=output.join("/n");
      */
    proh = prjlist.replace(/&/g, '<br>');
    status = statuss.replace(/&/g, '<br>');

    var Obj = {
      projectName: '<h3>' + responseText[j].projectName + '</h3>',
      projectDescription: '<p>' + proh + '<p>',
      currentStatus: '<b>' + "Current Status:" + '</b>' + '<br>' + status
    }
  }
}

statuss += '</ul>';
```

For these types of issues, I would recommend using the developer tools that are available in modern browsers to troubleshoot. Using `Inspect` element in Chrome for example, is really useful, and you could have caught this really quickly.

Comment: Sorry, should be `statuss +=`. I have updated my answer

Comment: now all other data of Current Status column getting added to this data.

Comment: @can you please help me on this.

Comment: I tried mocking up the collections in your code, and I don't see any issues. The bullets are rendering fine. Check the fiddle I created https://jsfiddle.net/chrisjsmith001/evkj0f27/1/. Just click the `Run` button if you are not familiar with this tool. In any case, I would love to help more, but your question was about fixing the `<ul><li>` issue. I know nothing about you project, nor the data being passed, so not a lot more I can do here.

Answer (score 0):

Due to small information on your code. I do have the same assumption with Anniket. And also  `projectDescription: '< p>'+ proh + '< p>'` , because you dont close the  `< /p>` correctly. Please provide a jsfiddle as Aniket suggested to have a better picture.

Comment: actually, I am using following code  statuss= '<ul><li>'+ responseText[j].currentStatus + '</li></ul>'; to list the elements.

Comment: I want to list the data in Current Status . Actually i am getting value from DB. so, jsfiddle it is difficult to get data. I have attached the screen shot of my output. As you can see, only bullet is coming in first record not all records

Answer (score 0):

The line where you are using `replace()` method, you are adding `<br>` tag.

The function of `<br>` tag is to move the content on next line.

So, the `<UL>` tag puts a bullet before each `<LI>` content, but you explicitly break it to move to next line, hence only one bullet is seen.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee <br> Bread</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

See the output of the above code. !!